# Why does this autocmd not work

Tags: vimrc

I write this line to the `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim` file, but nothing happens when I create a new C file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.c read ~/skeleton/c
```

Afterwards, I added this line to $MYVIMRC:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.c echo 123
```

Then the skeleton started to be added to new C files.

Why?

Comment: Thank to the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually it works, but probably not the way you think.

1. Autocommands are invoked in sequence. It's `BufNewFile` and/or `BufRead` that are used by `ftplugin` to `set filetype` which results in `FileType` autocommand which, in turn, does `source` all your stuff. So you've already missed `BufNewFile` *for that particualr buffer*.
2. Nonetheless, `autocmd` without `<buffer>` specification *is global*, so you've set it up for later. And did it wrong: each time `FileType c` is triggered, you add another instance of `read` for later buffers.

So your options are:

1. Add it to vimrc:

   ```
   augroup MySkeletons | au!
       autocmd BufNewFile *.c read ~/skeleton/c
   augroup end
   ```
2. Manually check if the current buffer is empty:

   In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

   ```
   if line('$') == 1 && empty(getline(1))
       read ~/skeleton/c
   endif
   ```

Comment: @eyalkarni It's possible but it's precisely what ftplugin does. So that's the reason why one never needs to trap `BufRead` himself (except to detect filetype).